# giveup sync on Mist, how do I access my ether on myetherwallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

After endless hours on trying to sync on Mist, I gave up. I read some posts about accessing ether via myetherwallet.com. I don't want to screwup on the process. Can someone walk me through how to do it, much appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to do with your ETH? As long as you've securely stored the private key of your ETH you technically have access to it.

Comment: I can't see my ether balance shown up on mist after I converted my BTC to ether. I tried to sync the thing for 9 months now. although I can see my ether transaction showup on etherscan, but i can't do anything with it. I just feel no confident at all in the network, want to exchange neo or some other alcoins with it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check your balance is actually not by unlocking your wallet. You only need your address in order to see your balance. It is not recommended that you enter your private key anywhere if you just want to check on the balance or see incoming / outgoing transactions. Instead...

ETH

https://etherscan.io/. Paste your address into the search bar and it will pull up your address and transaction history.

Tokens

https://ethplorer.io/ allows you to easily see token balances and transfers.

You can also see all tokens on https://etherscan.io/ now. Your balances are in the dropdown in the header section thingy. Your transfers can be viewed on the ["Token Transfers"](https://etherscan.io)

---

You can access your wallet on MEW when you are ready to send by selecting your keystore file on https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction

---

Security

Please make sure to bookmark MyEtherWallet.com, always check your URL whenever dealing with crypto, and consider installing MetaMask or EAL to protect yourself from phishing websites across the crypto currency space.

EAL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/etheraddresslookup/pdknmigbbbhmllnmgdfalmedcmcefdfn

Or

MetaMask: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn